# Data are wiped at least once a day (docker instance)

Tags: mongodb, docker, moleculer

My data is deleted every day. The mongo server run under docker, and i never encounter this issue on my local computer.
On the docker side:

The mongo setup is set to persistant data
volumes: - mongodata:/data/db
There is no rebuild of the mongo instance from docker (the wipe happen during the uptime)
I found the db files in the docker instance, there is only one instance of the files, dates are old enough (mongod.lock is 10 days old)
I looking in the docker logs, and i see this Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote cant it be related ?
Thank you

Comment: Have yout tried to look at the data in your MongoDB? E.g. you can use a tool like MongoDB Compass or MongoExpress.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.